# ffmpeg loop sound in part of video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatenate a few inputs, and loop a sound during the time of one input.
My inputs are:

- intro.mp4
- jpg suite in "pics" folder -> pics/%04d.jpg
- loop.mp3
- outro.mp4

What i want to achive :

[image: video schema]

What i have so far:

```
ffmpeg -y -i intro.mp4 -r 25 -i "pics/%04d.jpg" -i outro.mp4 -i loop.mp3 -filter_complex
"[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [3:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]"
-map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -crf 20 -r 25
-movflags +faststart -c:a aac -b:a 192k output.mp4
```

But that does not loop "loop.wav". I'v tried "-loop 1" before "-i loop.mp3" but that gives me this error : "Option loop not found."

ffmpeg version : 20170620-ae6f6d4-win64-static

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it in two concat steps. And the audio will drop out at the loop point.

```
ffmpeg -y -i intro.mp4 -i "pics/%04d.jpg" -i outro.mp4 -f lavfi -i amovie=loop.mp3:loop=15,asetpts=N/SR/TB
 -filter_complex
    "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [3:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v12] [a12];
     [v12][a12][2:v:0] [2:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]"
 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -r 25 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0
 -crf 20 -movflags +faststart -c:a aac -b:a 192k output.mp4
```

When joining the last segment, the concat filter stops at the shorter of the two streams. Hence the use of two concat filters.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Unfortunately, this script will loop the sound 15 times, and will show the last jpg until the 15 loops are complete.

Comment: Oops. The doc is wrong: `The concat filter will use the duration of the longest stream in each segment (except the last one), and if necessary pad shorter audio streams with silence. `. You will  have to mux the middle audio and video separately (with -shortest) and then concat.